# Apache Drill 'Failure in Starting Embedded drillbit'

Tags: apache, apache-drill

I have drill on a vm and was successfully able to connect to it. I restarted the vm after a power outage and now when I try to start drill in embedded mode - I get the following message

```
  Error: Failure in starting embedded Drillbit: java.net.UnknownHostException: xxxx.localdomain: xxxx.localdomain: Name or service not known (state=,code=0)
```

Is there a dependency that I need to restart?

Comment: Found a solution - drill was not accepting xxxx.localdomain as hostname. changed hostname to xxxx and am able to get drill working. Looks like the hostname got reset when I restarted the machine.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify /etc/hosts has entry for that domain with the inet ip. Hope this resolve your problem.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11337865)

Comment: I faced same issue and resolved in this way.... that is the reason I'm sharing this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Please add an entry to /etc/hosts like "127.0.0.1 yourhostname" which will solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Also works adding in /etc/hosts something like:

```
# keeping in mind that 192.168.0.10 is the ip of your server
127.0.0.1 localhost
192.168.0.10 your-server-01
```